# Implements filterable interface for adapter that is dynamically populated

Tags: android, adapter

How to keep original data for an adapter that is dynamically populated, need to snapshot data just before search request by the user on listview>
I'm implementing Filterable interface in myadapter, and cannot copy original data on constructor as my list is already empty and shall be populated later.

```
private Filter filteredList = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        List<ITEMMODEL> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
            filtered.addAll(itemsFull);
        } else {
            for (ITEMMODEL item : itemsFull) {
                Log.d(TAG,item.getName());
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                    filtered.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filtered;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll((List)filterResults.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};



public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ItemsProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    itemListAdapter.clear();
    while ((cursor.moveToNext())) {
        itemListAdapter.addItem(itemFromCursor(cursor));
    }
```

}

Comment: Pls show the code that add data/dataList into the adapter.

Comment: @I_A_Mok I updated the code above "Fragment::onResume"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inside the adapter, modifiy **clear()** method like this:

```
        @Override
        public void clear() {
            super.clear();
            itemsFull.clear();
        }
```

and **addItem()** method to add item to both lists (items and itemsFull). Hope that helps!